# hot to get pixel per meter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, rasterizing

I have a vector shapefile which is in unit of 'Meter' presenting boundary of overall Germany. I am converting it into raster format based on each pixel representing 300 Meters respectively. After conversion I accessed inmage information using imfinfo() in matlab. However the result is giving me the unit value is in "Inches" I am quite confused at the moment and do not know what to do to convert inches to meters as a pixel size unit. Would you please give me some idea?

```
`% Code
R6 = shaperead('B6c.shp');
%Nord
XN6 = double(R6(4).X); YN6 = double(R6(4).Y);
XN6min = min(XN6(XN6>0)); XNmax = max(XN6);
YN6min = min(YN6(YN6>0)); YNmax = max(YN6);
%Bayern
XB6 = double(R6(7).X); YB6 = double(R6(7).Y);
XB6min = min(XB6(XB6>0)); XB6max = max(XB6);
YB6min = min(YB6(YB6>0)); YB6max = max(YB6);
%Schleswig-Holstein
XSH6 = double(R6(9).X); YSH6 = double(R6(9).Y);
XSH6min = min(XSH6(XSH6>0)); XSH6max = max(XSH6);
YSH6min = min(YSH6(YSH6>0)); YSH6max = max(YSH6);
%Sachsen
XS6 = double(R6(6).X); YS6 = double(R6(6).Y);
XS6min = min(XS6(XS6>0)); XS6max = max(XS6);
YS6min = min(YS6(YS6>0)); YS6max = max(YS6);
dx = round(XS6max-XN6min);
dy = round(YSH6max-YB6min);
M = round((dx)/300);enter code here N = round((dy)/300);
A6 = zeros(M,N); %initiating image matrix based on 4 limiting States
%transformation from world to pixel coordinates
xpix_bw =(((XBW-XN6min)*M)/dx)'; 
ypix_bw =(((YBW-YB6min)*N)/dy)';
xbw6=round(xpix_bw); xbw6=xbw6(~isnan(xbw6));
ybw6=round(ypix_bw); ybw6=ybw6(~isnan(ybw6));
%line drawing
for i=1:1:length(xbw6)-1
    j=i+1;
    x1=xbw6(i); x2=xbw6(j); y1=ybw6(i); y2=ybw6(j);
    nn=atan2((y2-y1),(x2-x1)); % azimuthal angle
if x2==x1
    l=abs(y2-y1);
else
    l = round((x2-x1)/cos(nn)); % horizontal distance
end
xx=zeros(l,1); %empty column
yy=zeros(l,1); %empty column
% creating line along slope distance
for i=1:1:l
    xx(i)=round(x1+cos(nn)*i); 
    yy(i)=round(y1+sin(nn)*i);
    A6(xx(i)+1,yy(i)+1) = 256;
end
end
imwrite(A6, 'Untitled_0506_300.tif','Resolution', 300);`
```

Comment: I don't think `imfinfo()` supports "pixel per meter". See [Exif tags](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html). The `ResolutionUnit` options are: "None", "inches", "cm". You can try writing [GeoTIFF](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geotiffwrite.html). I never tried it.

Comment: I am going to try as you suggest. In any case it is always good ask a opinion of experts. I am attaching my code that I used to convert. Please feel free to point my mistake if there is one.

Comment: I am no expert... I am trying to help, and hoping I am not doing the opposite.

Comment: let's see the result after my trial. I think ur right.

Comment: TIFF files store resolution in pixels per inch or pixels per cm. The best you can do is convert your resolution (which is 1/300 px/m by the way) into one of those units, and deal with the weird result.

Comment: My question now is that until which point of my coding it was meter. I mean if I convert the inch into metter maanually then from where should I start?

Comment: Depending on what you're actually using this for, it might be SUPER important to realize that if your pixels at center image are 300 square meters,the pixels as you move to the edges will have a different physical area/pixel value based on camera sensor size & shape, focal distance, and the lense you're using.

Comment: I am integrating German 16 states into raster data from vector shape file. I have 23 different students data. Quality analysis will be based on area&perimeter. So it's important to focus on optimal cell size. When I calculate image size(M,N) its different for each student. I could not obtain 23 same sized matrix from conversion. So I created maximum possible reference matrix and wrote my pixel coordinates in it. I integrate the datasets by summing all intensity values of the matrixes.  So the reference matrix is changing cell size into 375. But I do not see better way to integrate it.